# Save Force Network data to JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I want to save the nodes and edges(links) data from a force network visualization to an JSON file.

I read in a JSON file as the source and I want the exact same format when I save the data.
I use FileSaver.js ( https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/ ) to create the JSON file:

```
var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(graph)], 
  {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});  
saveAs(blob, "graphData.JSON");
```

The problem is that the Force Network function converts the `source:` and `target:` node array references to their values in the node array. This means that my source data:

```
{
  "nodesData":[
    {"id":0,"label":"Zero","x":360,"y":40,"fixed":true},
    {"id":1,"label":"One","x":620,"y":20,"fixed":true},
    {"id":2,"label":"Two","x":620,"y":80,"fixed":true}
  ],
  "edgesData":[
    {"id":0,"source":0,
            "target":1},
    {"id":1,"source":0,
             "target":2}
  ]
}
```

is saved as:

```
{  
  "nodesData":[
     {"id":0,"label":"Zero","x":360,"y":40,"fixed":true,"index":0,"weight":2,"px":360,"py":40},
     {"id":1,"label":"One","x":620,"y":20,"fixed":1,"index":1,"weight":1,"px":620,"py":20},
     {"id":2,"label":"Two","x":620,"y":80,"fixed":true,"index":2,"weight":1,"px":620,"py":80}
  ],
  "edgesData":[
    {"id":0,"source":{"id":0,"label":"Zero","x":360,"y":40,"fixed":true,"index":0,"weight":2,"px":360,"py":40},
            "target":{"id":1,"label":"One","x":620,"y":20,"fixed":1,"index":1,"weight":1,"px":620,"py":20}
    },
    {"id":1,"source":{"id":0,"label":"Zero","x":360,"y":40,"fixed":true,"index":0,"weight":2,"px":360,"py":40},
            "target":{"id":2,"label":"Two","x":620,"y":80,"fixed":true,"index":2,"weight":1,"px":620,"py":80}
    }
  ]
}
```

My goal is to load this newly saved JSON file into a force network visualization at a later time. However, reloading the file as currently exported causes link construction to fail. How can I export to a JSON file that matches the original format for the `source:` and `target:` references?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways of either restoring your original data structure or manipulating the way D3 matches the `source` and `target` values to the nodes. The easiest approach will be to convert the object references in `edgesData` back to index-based or value-based references before serializing to JSON:

```
graph.edgesData.forEach(e => { 
  e.source = e.source.id;
  e.target = e.target.id;
});
```

Doing so yields the original structure which will be understood by your existing code.

```js
var graph = {  
  "nodesData":[
     {"id":0,"label":"Zero","x":360,"y":40,"fixed":true,"index":0,"weight":2,"px":360,"py":40},
     {"id":1,"label":"One","x":620,"y":20,"fixed":1,"index":1,"weight":1,"px":620,"py":20},
     {"id":2,"label":"Two","x":620,"y":80,"fixed":true,"index":2,"weight":1,"px":620,"py":80}
  ],
  "edgesData":[
    {"id":0,"source":{"id":0,"label":"Zero","x":360,"y":40,"fixed":true,"index":0,"weight":2,"px":360,"py":40},
            "target":{"id":1,"label":"One","x":620,"y":20,"fixed":1,"index":1,"weight":1,"px":620,"py":20}
    },
    {"id":1,"source":{"id":0,"label":"Zero","x":360,"y":40,"fixed":true,"index":0,"weight":2,"px":360,"py":40},
            "target":{"id":2,"label":"Two","x":620,"y":80,"fixed":true,"index":2,"weight":1,"px":620,"py":80}
    }
  ]
};

graph.edgesData.forEach(e => { 
  e.source = e.source.id;
  e.target = e.target.id;
});

console.log(graph);
```

Comment: Something tells me that the XY problem strikes again... +1 anyway.

Comment: I was able to round-trip the data back into the application using this approach. This will allow me to "save state" of a graph by saving out to JSON.  Thank you.